# Can Replacement schema be put in a single statement?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

is the following a theorem of ZFC?

$$\forall \varphi \forall A  \ [\forall x \in A \exists \theta: V_\theta  \models \exists! y \varphi(x,y) \to \\  \exists \alpha: \forall x \in A \exists ! y \in V_\alpha: V_\alpha \models \varphi(x,y)]$$

Notice that the above is a single sentence!

Comment: What is $\varphi$? You cannot have quantifiers ranging over formulas in a first order sentence

Comment: In Second-Order Logic

Comment: @Alessandro Codenotti, $\varphi$ is an *object* of the universe of discourse that stands for a formula, so it can be quantified upon. This is an indirect way of writting, see Hamkins comment https://mathoverflow.net/questions/391651/can-we-have-sf-v-htd-how-it-relates-to-sf-v-hod#comment998892_391651 However I'm not sure if it can be written as such, and I'm not sure if it is equivalent to replacement either.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes of course, but I'm speaking about ZFC as formulated in first order logic.

Comment: Since the formula is internal it cannot be used in the axiom's syntactical structure. You need to say that there is some suitable $\alpha$ where $V_\alpha\models\varphi$, or something like that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I didn't mean for it to be an axiom, I was thinking if it is a  *theorem* of ZFC.

Comment: Okay, but it's the same thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, do you mean in the anticedent, because I already said that in the consequent.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, if $\varphi$ is a non-standard formula, what does it even mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, may be $$\forall \varphi \forall A \ [\forall x \in A \exists \theta: V_\theta \models \exists! y \varphi(x,y) \to \\ \exists B \exists \alpha: B=\{y \in V_\alpha \mid \exists x \in A :V_\alpha \models \varphi(x,y) \}]$$

Comment: That is better, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is in fact **disprovable**. The point is that we can use $\varphi$ to relate elements of $A$ to **specific** leveles of the cumulative hierarchy, preventing "simultaneous unique existence."

Take for example the formula $\varphi(x,y)$ which is the conjunction of the following clauses:

- There are either $17$ or $42$ ordinals in the whole universe.
- $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $y\in\{0,1\}$.
- If $x=0$ then: $y=1$ only if there are $17$ ordinals in the universe.
- If $x=1$ then: $y=1$ only if there are $42$ ordinals in the universe.

Consider what happens if $A=\{0,1\}$. For $x=0$ we get that $V_\alpha$ thinks that there is a unique $y$ with $\varphi(x,y)$ iff $\alpha=42$ (since this prevents $y=1$ via the third bulletpoint), and for $x=1$ we get that $V_\alpha$ thinks that there is a unique $y$ with $\varphi(x,y)$ iff $\alpha=17$ (since this prevents $y=1$ via the fourth bulletpoint).

Now use the fact that $17\not=42$.

---

You can avoid this if you require the set of $\alpha$s providing "unique existence" to be appropriately large. Specifically, say you demand that for each $x\in A$ the set of $\alpha$ such that $V_\alpha\models\exists!y\varphi(x,y)$ is a **club**. Then since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves that the intersection of set-many clubs is again club, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ would prove that there is a club of ordinals $\beta$ such that ($A\in V_\beta$ and) $V_\beta\models\forall a\in A\exists!y\varphi(a,y)$.

However, there's a subtlety here. Note that I used the hypothesis that the set of relevant $V$-indices **is** a club. A more natural hypothesis might be "**contains** a club." However, this isn't expressible in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ since we can't quantify over classes! We *could*, fixing $n$, say "contains a $\Sigma_n$-definable club" but that wouldn't be nearly as rich.

---

EDIT: in fact, $\mathsf{ZF}$ is not finitely axiomatizable over $\mathsf{Z}$ at all! This is a quick variation of the usual **reflection argument** that $\mathsf{ZF}$ is not finitely axiomatizable. Specifically, we use the fact that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves "$V_\beta\models\mathsf{Z}$ whenever $\beta$ is a strong limit cardinal." We then argue in $\mathsf{ZF}$, for a fixed $\mathsf{ZF}$-theorem $\theta$, that there is a strong limit cardinal $\beta$ with $V_\beta\models\theta$ and hence $V_\beta\models\mathsf{Z}+\theta$. Consequently, there is no single sentence $\theta$ such that $\mathsf{Z}+\theta\dashv\vdash\mathsf{ZF}.$

And the situation is identical with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ vs. $\mathsf{ZC}$.

Comment: Yes! I think the proof that ZFC is not finitely axiomatizable is due to Montague.

Comment: @Zuhair That's a different result - I'm talking about finite axiomatizability **over $\mathsf{Z}$ (or $\mathsf{ZC}$)**. That's not the same thing at all; for example, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is trivially finitely axiomatizable over itself!

Comment: @Zuhair I was making things overly complicated; I've added the argument.