# Is this replacement sentence consistent with Z? If so what's its consistency strength over Z + Ranks?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axioms

This question comes in continuation with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139559/can-replacement-schema-be-put-in-a-single-statement/4140220?noredirect=1#comment8567011_4140220).

Is the following replacement like statement disprovable in $\sf ZFC$? And if not, then what's the consistency strength of adding it to $\sf Z + \forall x \exists \alpha: x \in V_\alpha$ ?

$$\forall \varphi \forall A \ [\forall x \in A \exists \alpha \forall \theta > \alpha:  V_\theta \models \exists! y \varphi(x,y) \to \\  \exists \beta: \forall x \in A \exists  y \in V_\beta: V_\beta \models \varphi(x,y)]$$

Comment: This is easily provable in $\mathsf{ZFC}$: given $\varphi$ and $A$, for $a\in A$ let $\alpha_a$ be the least ordinal such that for all $\theta>\alpha$ we have $V_\theta\models\exists!y\varphi(x,y)$. Applying replacement to the class function $F:a\mapsto \alpha_a$, let $\beta=\sup(ran(F))$.

Comment: So it is consistent with Z + Ranks. But what is the strength of adding it to that theory? It must be weaker than ZFC, right? because no single sentence over Z can reach into ZFC.

Comment: No idea - the gap between $\mathsf{Z}$ and $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ is not something I understand well at all. Mathias' various papers might be relevant, but they're quite material-dense. At a glance, though, your principle seems to be a consequence of $\mathsf{Z}$ + $\Pi_1$-replacement.